# Order of viewWillAppear calls

Tags: ios

If I have multiple view controllers being presented and dismissed in any order, can I be sure that iOS calls `viewWillAppear` methods in the right order (i.e. order of appearance)?

I cannot find any specific information about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you need to know about `viewWillAppear` from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> **This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.** You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use this method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Only thing that comes to mind that might not be absolutely clear is that this callback is called on the presenting view controller when presented view controller is going to be dismissed (so presenting view controller is going to appear again).

Therefore if `A` is a root, `A.viewWillAppear` will be called before it will appear on the screen. Then, if `A` presents `B`, just before `B` becomes visible, `B.viewWillAppear` will be called. And when `B` is being dismissed, `A.viewWillAppear` will get called again, since its view will appear again.

Comment: Ok, but how about this: `A` is root. `A` presents `B`. `B` is dismissed and then `A` presents `C` immediately. Can I be sure that the order of `viewWillAppear` will be `1) A.viewWillAppear 2) B.viewWillAppear 3) A.viewWillAppear 4) c.viewWillAppear`? For `viewDidAppear` I would say it's pretty obvious, but I'm worried that there might be some things getting done under the hood in between `will` and actual appearing on the screen that might take significant amount of time to mess up the ordering.

Comment: @dontgonearthecastle well, the documentation says so (see my answer), so I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be so.. I was able to also confirm it empirically (which you can do yourself). what is the reason that you doubt it?

Comment: The documentation only states that `viewWillAppear` will be called before the view appears on screen. There is no explicit statement that the OS will be calling those callbacks in order. So, I assume, that there might be a situation, where (looking at my previous example) `A.viewWillAppear` might be called after `C.viewWillAppear`. My doubts come from no explicit confirmation ;) I know, that it probably works this way, but I'm looking for proof :)

Comment: @dontgonearthecastle well, I believe it is expected to go that way - because in fact `A` comes to screen first before `C` after dismissing `B` - it has to, because `A` will have to present `C` (therefore `A` has to come before `C`, and `A.viewWillAppear` will come before `C.viewWillAppear`).. and I never faced a situation in which it would not work that way..

Comment: I know that it might be useful in very rare situations, but I just came across one :p Unfortunately, there are many things in iOS that are 'expected to go that way' and no one really knows what way they go :p

Comment: @dontgonearthecastle what's the setup when it happens that way? just out of curiosity..

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. It's not happening to call viewWillAppear out of order. I'm just trying to make sure It's not going to happen :)

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear()` is called the first time the view is displayed and it is also called when the view is displayed again, so it can be called multiple times during the life of the view controller object.

It’s called when the view is about to appear as a result of the user tapping the back button, closing dialog, or when the view controller’s tab is selected in a tab bar controller, or a variety of other reasons. Make sure to call `super.viewWillAppear()` at some point in the implementation

Comment: It's not an answer to my question though ;)